# Given that $var = 1, how come $var = $var === 0 doesn't return false?

Tags: php

Firstly, I am dealing with 1s and 0s here and I'm well aware that 1 == true and 0 == false. However I'm curious as to why this doesn't work:

```php
$var = 1;
echo $var; /* 1 */
$var = $var === 0;
echo $var; /* Nothing */
```

Is there a reason the second instance of `echo $var;` isn't returning 0 (false) and instead returns nothing?

Equally, `!$var` also returns nothing. What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: @DipeshParmar surely that's even more reason to return false if the data types do not match (although not very practical). For reference though, the same happens with `==`.

Comment: Because you are casting to string?

Comment: @ZombieHunter *"Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values."* http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting They *could* have chosen `'0'` (zero as a string) instead, since that also allows a roundtrip conversion; but they didn't.

Comment: @deceze: Thanks for the feedback. Already removed my comment because I followed the link in your answer. +1 for providing the helpful link, -1 to the PHP designers :-)

Comment: @Zombie Meh. IMO it's just about as illogical as anything else. You wouldn't want `'false'`, since that's `true`, and `'0'` would be pretty controversial as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because

```
$var = $var === 0;
```

Can be read as:

```
$var = ($var === 0);   // sets $var to the result of the comparison
```

in the correct precedence. Now when `$var` is `1`, `($var === 0)` returns `false` which is represented as an empty string when output via `echo`.

You can see the "0" by explicitly casting the `false` value as an integer using the `(int)` operator:

```
echo (int)$var;        // ouputs "0"
```

`false` values are represented by PHP as an empty string because PHP variables have no type in general. There is no boolean, int, or string - only in the internal representation of a value (called ZVAL in the Zend Engine).

In PHP code, ZVALs are automatically cast to the type which matches best, depending on where you use it. This is called [type juggling<sup>Docs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

And since PHP is meant to produce websites, empty variables (false == 0 == "") [are represented with an empty string in the output<sup>Docs</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting).

Comment: Oh I see, I wasn't aware PHP treated false as an empty string. Interesting!

Comment: @James It doesn't "treat `false` as an empty string", it *converts* `false` *to* an empty string when casting from booleans to strings. Big difference.

Answer (score 5):

It's easier to show what's happening with `var_dump()` instead of `echo`, as the type is shown:

```
$var = 1;
var_dump($var); /* int(1) */
$var = $var === 0;
var_dump($var); /* bool(false) */
```

`$var` at the end is false because `$var === 0` evaluates to false, and then that value is being assigned to `$var`.

Nothing is being outputted with the final `echo` as boolean false evaluates to an empty string: see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: false returns nothing. But if this would have been his question, he'd have written "why does `echo false` return nothing?"

Answer (score 3):

`0` equals `false` in a loose comparison, but `0` *is* not `false`. The variable is set to `false`, and `false` echo'd into a string is `""` (an empty string).

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know 2 things in order to figure this out:

- **[Operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)**

You can notice that `=` has a lower precedence than `===`, thus the expression `$var = $var === 0;` becomes `$var = ($var === 0);` - and in this situation `$var` contains `(bool)false`

- **[Casting (or type juggling)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)**

Since [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) operates on strings, `$var` will be converted to string. And the boolean value `false` results in am empty string when converted to a string (so is `NULL` by the way).

Answer (score 1):

If you add var_dump($var); to the end of that little nugget you will see that $var = false.

that is because $var === 0; is false;

Comment: why does not echo display the value of $var false ?

Answer (score 1):

Key part of the code is this:

```
echo $var;
```

The [echo](http://php.net/echo) construct receives and generates strings. If your variable is boolean, the appropriate [conversion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) applies:

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". **Boolean FALSE is
>   converted to "" (the empty string)**. This allows conversion back and
>   forth between boolean and string values.

This is the reason why `echo` is not a good debugging tool given that flattening everything into a string can lead to loss of valuable information unless the tool you use knows how to extract that info (and `echo` doesn't). For that, [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) is often a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

`$var = $var === 0;` assigns the result of `$var === 0` (which is `false`) to `$var`. And `echo false` does not produce any output.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `===`, it also matches the data type. 
So in this case, `1 === TRUE`  is not TRUE.

```
$var = 1;
echo $var; /* 1 */
$var = $var === 0;
echo $var; /* Nothing */
```

In your third line, `$var === 0` evaluates to `FALSE`, so, it's like you put

```
$var = FALSE;
```

You can't print boolean characters. 
However, if you `var_dump($var);` , you will see that it's a boolean FALSE.